# vuforia sample application code 100 error in airplane mode

Tags: xcode, vuforia

I need to update an iOS app working with Vuforia.

The app compiles and runs normal, but I need to test airplane mode. In airplane mode, when trying to use the device's camera, I get this error:

`Error initializing AR:Error Domain=vuforia_sample_application Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed."`

I've been unable to find out what this error is.

What is error code 100? Also, does Vuforia need a web connection?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently `Vuforia` DOES indeed need an internet connection. It's stated so in the Vuforia [**FAQ for License Manager**](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/FAQ/License-Manager-FAQ) under `Does my app need to connect to the internet?`

They say your app requires a one-time internet connection to validate the `license key` and activate `Vuforia` functionality, but I don't know if that sticks true.

But I've heard some people say that it because there was an extra blank character after the license key in the `Inspector` view of `ARCamera` - removing the space resulted in a running version of the software.

See if it works out for you. If it does, then wooohoo.